# select a list of rows from this table format based on distinct fk2 and > date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to select a list of rows from this table format based on distinct fk2 and > date?

Table

pk  fk1 fk2 value   date

1  1   1   100     1/1/2009

2  1   2   110     1/1/2009

3  1   2   120     5/1/2009

4  1   3   130     1/1/2009

I would like it to return rows 1,3,4

I only pass in fk1

Select * from table where fk1=1 'and the row with the latest date for each fk2?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from table t where t.fk1=1 and t.date=( select max(date) from table where fk2=t.fk2 and fk1=t.fk1)
```